# Setup protractor-cucumber e2e Angular tests and use Jasmine?

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, cucumber

I was wondering if it's possible to use Jasmine library when using protractor and cucumber.

`protractor.conf.js`:

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/features/*.feature'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: './src/steps/**/*.ts',
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
  }
};
```

`tsconfig.e2e.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

My steps definition:

```
import { ChangeProfilePage } from './change-profile.po';
import { When, Then, Before } from 'cucumber';


let page: ChangeProfilePage;

Before(() => {
  page = new ChangeProfilePage();
  page.goToChangeProfile();
  page.init();
});

When('The user fills in the form with valid inputs', () => {
  page.setFaroId("123BA");
  page.setFirstName("Baptiste");
  page.setLastName("Arnaud");
  page.setEmail("bapt@gaz.com");
  page.setAdmin(true);
});

Then('The user clicks on the submit button', () => {
  page.submitForm();
});

Then('The user should see the {string} indicator', (string) => {
  expect(page.getSubmitMessage()).toEqual(true);
});
```

It prints out a Warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
```

And it says `expect is not defined`.

What do I do wrong here? Also, the browser opens up and isn't redirecting to desire location. There's `data:,` in the url tab. What does it mean?

Comment: Can you provide more detailed stack trace. that would help to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use cucumber as test framework, you can't use Jasmine without import it.

From your given code, you want to use the assertion api: `expect` supplied by Jasmine in your cucumber test script.  Actually, you can use other assertion lib instead.

Like `chai` and `chai-as-promised` which is independent on any test framework.

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {

   onPrepare: function() {

      var chai = require('chai');

      chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));

      global.expect = chai.expect;
   }
};

// test script

// validate non-promise value (can't use `eventually`)
expect('a string').to.equal('b string');

// validate promise value (must use `eventually`)
expect(xx.getText()).to.eventually.equal('yyyyy')
```

Comment: I already use Jasmine as assertion lib for unit tests in my angular project so I don't want to install another assertion library

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this answer still uses chai.expect and not Jasmine. What do I need to use as global.expect to use Jasmine expects?

Comment: Jasmine and Cucumber are different test framework,  but Protractor only supports to use one test framework per running via the `framework` setting in protractor conf.js.   If you indeed to use both of them, you need to look into their source code to find out a way how to import them via `require()` .  I tried look into Jasmine source code, but fail to figure out the way.